# Move a photo from one album to another with Facebook API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-fql

Is it possible to move a photo from one album to another using the graph api (or failing that, FQL, which I know less about)?

I see how I can add a photo to an album, so in theory I could download a photo, delete it, upload it to a different album, but that'd be pretty cumbersome and a lengthy operation.

I suppose it could be thought of one of two ways:
- Change the album to which a photo belongs
- Move a photo with a given ID from one album to another

I'm starting to fear its not possible, so hoping I'm missing something.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like deleting is not possible (it was at one time, but they've disabled it).  So upload-delete won't work.

From what I can tell they do not expose a way to do this at all.  I know it's a longshot, but do they have a way to request API functionality (rather than just reporting bugs)?

Answer (score 0):

First, unless your app uploaded the photo to the source album, I don't think your app will be able to remove it from the source album. Most Facebook data is tagged to prevent apps from interfering with one another or with the user's manually uploaded data.

I don't know of an API to "move" a photo from one album to another. Downloading+upload+delete is the obvious approach. I don't know from where you got the photo, so if it's already available anywhere you can skip the download stage. Unfortunately, the last I checked Create Photo had a limitation which would not let you upload a photo from the Facebook CDN.

You can easily script this from your desktop using http://facebookpsmodule.codeplex.com, otherwise, it shouldn't be too tricky from a Facebook Application with Facebook C# SDK.